# Does the package.xml file in Habitat project help to deploy to server and how?

Tags: habitat, gulp

I'm able to update the `package.xml` using below script in command-line:

```
gulp -b "D:\projects\Habitat" --color --gulpfile "D:\projects\Habitat\Gulpfile-ci.js" CI-Do-magic
```

`package.xml` is located here on Github - https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/package.xml

Please help in understanding the purpose of `package.xml` and how it is used for deployment (if it is meant for it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the use of this package is internal to Sitecore employees who maintain and publish the demo on GitHub: https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/releases

They update the file, upload it to Sitecore, manually create a Sitecore package with it and upload that package to GitHub. Maybe they to the above automatically using custom CI tasks.

I have done some work with the scripts used to generate this package some months ago. I found out the users/roles are not included in the file anymore. That's a problem of recent official Habitat packages from some time.

Answer (score 4):

After reading @jflheureux's answer and little bit digging around Habitat release package.

First Aha!, it is a Sitecore package definition file which contains everything - content items, security items, files. Second Aha!, we can `Generate Package` using `Sitecore Rocks` by using `package.xml` which is a similar process as `Package Designer` in `Sitecore Desktop`.

To test this:

> I just had to rename `package.xml` to `HabitatBuild.package` and open this file using Visual Studio with Sitecore Rocks preinstalled.

Manual steps to make this working:

1. Rename `package.xml` to `HabitatBuild.package`
2. Open Visual Studio
3. Make sure you have Sitecore Rocks extension installed in Visual Studio
4. Make sure you have Sitecore website connection added in Sitecore Explorer
5. Open `HabitatBuild.package` in Visual Studio
6. Select the Sitecore website for connection in pop-up dialog
7. Click on `Build` button

Still, I need to find out how to automate this process.

Thanks again @jflheureux for helping indirectly :)

### Update

We can use the `Package Designer` directly with `package.xml`, just drop the file in `Data/packages` folder of Sitecore instance and Open the `package.xml` from `Package Designer` and generate the package.